# When is a recurrence the sum of the powers of the roots of a polynomial?

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, recurrence-relations, symmetric-polynomials

Newton's formula allows one to calculate the sum $S_n(P)$ of the $n$th powers of the roots of a given monic polynomial $P$ without finding the roots explicitly. (This works even when the roots themselves don't have a closed form.) If the polynomial is in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, then the sum is an integer; further, the sequence $(S_n)^\infty_{n=1}$ is a homogeneous linear recurrence of order $\deg(P).$

I'm interested in turning this around: given a homogeneous linear recurrence and an integer sequence $(x_n)^\infty_{n=1}$ satisfying this recurrence, how can I tell if there is a monic integer polynomial $P$ such that $x_n$ is the sum of the $n$th powers of the roots of $P$? (If so, finding such a polynomial is also of interest.)

Comment: You may just consider the characteristic polynomial of your sequence. The recurrence for the power sums is given by the same polynomial due to the Cayley-Hamilton theorem.

Comment: For instance, the power sums of $q(x)=x^2-3x+1$ given by $p_n=\zeta_1^n+\zeta_2^n$ fulfill $p_{n+2}=3 p_{n+1}-p_{n}$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: So if the recurrence has characteristic polynomial $P(x)$ and the sums of the $n$th powers of the roots of $P(x)$ do not coincide with the $x_n$, then $(x_n)^\infty_{n=1}$ cannot be expressed as the sums of the roots of any polynomial. Correct?

Comment: That was exactly my idea.

Answer (score 1):

If the polynomial in the denominator of the generating functions has only simple roots (i.e. roots with multiplicity 1), a full partial fraction decomposition of the generating function with only have terms $\sim 1/(x-r)$ with roots $r$, and replacing these terms by their geometric series shows that the original series has the required shape (keyword: Binet formula). For roots of higher order, the partial fraction decomposition has also other terms.